# Groups not being populated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

Im making a react app that should draw the teams on the 4 pots to 8 groups with 4 teams each, and the team that has isHolder: true should be on the group A, without the isHolder part it was everything working, but when i remove the isHolder from the shuffledPote1 and add it to the group A the group H gets no teams, i think it may be due to the shuffledPote1 not having 8 teams anymore, but since i already added the isHolder team to group A it should work, but it isnt

I expect to draw 4 teams to each group, with the isHolder team on the group A

```
export type Time = {
    name: string;
    rank?: number;
    pot: number;
    isHolder?: boolean;
    nacionalidade: string;
    isFromPre?: boolean;
};

const teams: Time[] = [
    {
        name: 'Flamengo',
        rank: 3,
        pot: 1,
        isHolder: true,
        nacionalidade: 'BRASIL',
    },
    { name: 'River Plate', rank: 1, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'ARGENTINA' },
    { name: 'Palmeiras', rank: 2, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'BRASIL' },
    { name: 'Boca Juniors', rank: 4, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'ARGENTINA' },
    { name: 'Nacional', rank: 6, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'Uruguai' },
    { name: 'Athletico-PR', rank: 7, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'BRASIL' },
    { name: 'Ind. del Valle', rank: 11, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'EQUADOR' },
    { name: 'Olimpia', rank: 14, pot: 1, nacionalidade: 'PARAGUAI' },
    { name: 'Libertad', rank: 16, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'PARAGUAI' },
    { name: 'Atlético Nacional', rank: 17, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'COLÔMBIA' },
    { name: 'Internacional', rank: 18, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'BRASIL' },
    { name: 'Barcelona', rank: 19, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'EQUADOR' },
    { name: 'Racing', rank: 22, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'ARGENTINA' },
    { name: 'Corinthians', rank: 24, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'BRASIL' },
    { name: 'Colo-Colo', rank: 28, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'CHILE' },
    { name: 'Fluminense', rank: 32, pot: 2, nacionalidade: 'BRASIL' },
    { name: 'Bolívar', rank: 33, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'BOLÍVIA' },
    { name: 'The Strongest', rank: 38, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'BOLÍVIA' },
    { name: 'Melgar', rank: 44, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'PERU' },
    { name: 'Alianza Lima', rank: 52, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'PERU' },
    { name: 'Argentinos Jrs.', rank: 55, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'ARGENTINA' },
    { name: 'Metropolitanos', rank: 97, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'VENEZUELA' },
    { name: 'Aucas', rank: 112, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'EQUADOR' },
    { name: 'Monagas', rank: 133, pot: 3, nacionalidade: 'VENEZUELA' },
    { name: 'Liverpool', rank: 165, pot: 4, nacionalidade: 'URUGUAI' },
    { name: 'Deportivo Pereira', rank: 205, pot: 4, nacionalidade: 'COLÔMBIA' },
    { name: 'Ñublense', rank: 230, pot: 4, nacionalidade: 'CHILE' },
    { name: 'Patronato', pot: 4, nacionalidade: 'ARGENTINA' },
    {
        name: 'Atlético-MG',
        rank: 11,
        pot: 4,
        nacionalidade: 'BRASIL',
        isFromPre: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Sporting Cristal',
        rank: 35,
        pot: 4,
        nacionalidade: 'PERU',
        isFromPre: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Cerro Porteño',
        rank: 15,
        pot: 4,
        nacionalidade: 'PARAGUAI',
        isFromPre: true,
    },
    {
        name: 'Independente Medellín',
        rank: 54,
        pot: 4,
        nacionalidade: 'COLÔMBIA',
        isFromPre: true,
    },
];

export default teams;
```

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import teams from './Teams';

interface Group {
    name: string;
    teams: string[];
}

const initialGroups: Group[] = [
    { name: 'A', teams: [] },
    { name: 'B', teams: [] },
    { name: 'C', teams: [] },
    { name: 'D', teams: [] },
    { name: 'E', teams: [] },
    { name: 'F', teams: [] },
    { name: 'G', teams: [] },
    { name: 'H', teams: [] },
];

function Grupos() {
    const [groups, setGroups] = useState<Group[]>(initialGroups);

    function Sortear() {
        groups.forEach((group) => (group.teams = []));

        const pote1 = teams.filter((team) => team.pot === 1);
        const pote2 = teams.filter((team) => team.pot === 2);
        const pote3 = teams.filter((team) => team.pot === 3);
        const pote4 = teams.filter((team) => team.pot === 4);

        const shuffledPote1 = shuffleArray(pote1);
        const shuffledPote2 = shuffleArray(pote2);
        const shuffledPote3 = shuffleArray(pote3);
        const shuffledPote4 = shuffleArray(pote4);

        const updatedGroups = [...initialGroups];

        // Find and remove the team with isHolder = true from its pot
        const holderTeam = shuffledPote1.find((team) => team.isHolder);
        if (holderTeam) {
            const holderTeamIndex = shuffledPote1.indexOf(holderTeam);
            shuffledPote1.splice(holderTeamIndex, 1);
        }

        // Add the holder team to group A

        for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            // Start from group A

            const timeSorteado1 = shuffledPote1.pop()?.name;
            const timeSorteado2 = shuffledPote2.pop()?.name;
            const timeSorteado3 = shuffledPote3.pop()?.name;
            const timeSorteado4 = shuffledPote4.pop()?.name;

            if (timeSorteado1 && timeSorteado2 && timeSorteado3 && timeSorteado4) {
                // Add the holder team as the first team in group A
                if (groups[i].name === 'A') {
                    groups[i].teams.push(holderTeam?.name);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado2);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado3);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado4);
                } else {
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado1);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado2);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado3);
                    groups[i].teams.push(timeSorteado4);
                }
            }
        }

        setGroups(updatedGroups);
    }

    function shuffleArray(array: any[]) {
        const shuffledArray = [...array];
        for (let i = shuffledArray.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
            [shuffledArray[i], shuffledArray[j]] = [
                shuffledArray[j],
                shuffledArray[i],
            ];
        }
        return shuffledArray;
    }

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col gap-6">
            <button className="self-start" onClick={Sortear}>
                Sortear
            </button>
            <div className="grid grid-cols-4 gap-5">
                {groups.map((group) => (
                    <div className="flex flex-col gap-1" key={group.name}>
                        <h2>Grupo {group.name}</h2>
                        <ul>
                            {group.teams.map((team, index) => (
                                <li key={index}>{team}</li>
                            ))}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Grupos;
```

Comment: The `splice()` function is a [mutating method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#copying_methods_and_mutating_methods), which means it will change the existing array.

Comment: But i need to mutate the array so when i draw the teams i don't add the holder team again to a group, don't i?

Comment: If that is the case, your `for` loop should not hard code the `i < 8` and instead use a length value on the array. Also, consider that using `pop()` will also mutate the array -- meaning your loop will not have the same number of elements each iteration.

Comment: I just saw my error, i was using `const timeSorteado1 = shuffledPote1.pop()?.name;` on every loop, even the one that should was not adding the timeSortedo1 to a group, but it was removing it from the array. And i also changed the `i < 8` to `i < groups.length`, thank you